# subclassing a proxy in ExtJS

Tags: ajax, extjs

i want to create my own ajax proxy in ExtJS.  i have subclasses the proxy class:

```
Ext.define('Ext.util.proxy.MyProxy', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.proxy.Server',
...
```

i am overriding doRequest

```
doRequest : function(operation, callback, scope) {
```

then i am making standard $.ajax calls.

my question: how do i handle the response?  i believe it requires processing the operation object, but have not found a clear description of what needs to be done.  this does not work:

```
operation.commitRecords(result.records);
operation.setCompleted();
operation.setSuccessful();
```

Comment: What's exactly a problem? You can always take existing `processResponse` method and see what you don't need and add new logic there.

Comment: you're awesome!  that got me over a hump.  i added this.buildRequest and this.processResponse.  however, why do i need to build a request?  i am not using it myself?  i feel like ExtJS does not provide a simple and clean separation of interests here.  could you explain why the request object is needed here?

Comment: buildRequest is used to create full request including any additional parameters (like sorting, paging etc)